# Android library modules sources not present in .aar file

Tags: android, module, android-library, aar

I'm writing an Android library. It depends on another Android library module.

- library
- librarymodule

`library` depends on `librarymodule` like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    ...
}

dependencies {
    ...
    implementation project(":librarymodule")
}
```

I would like to export `library` as .arr file to use in applications but the content of `librarymodule` is not packaged into the resulting .aar file. 
If I try to use this library in an application it produces the following error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "class from librarymodule" on path: ...

How can I package the sources of `librarymodule` into the `library.aar` file to ship it as one library?

Comment: gradle will not build librarymodule's code into library.aar, android library module just includes its own source code and resources. If you want to use library.aar in an application correctly, you can upload librarymodule to a maven repository, and let library module references it through maven. when you use library.aar in an application, it'll download librarymodule.aar automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there no other way? Must my library ba a big monolith without being able to reuse modules?

Comment: you can build librarymodule source code into jar if it does not include android resources, like layouts, strings,drawables etc. then let library references it through jar dependency

Comment: Indeed. That's what I'll probably do. Unfortunately, it limits me from using Android tools like Retrofit or Room in the modules. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a `pom.xml` file that includes the necessary sources to be used in the app.

Comment: I did. It didn't work. Maybe I'm doing it wrong, do you have some guide?